# Headless Raspberry Pi has different IP address than the interface it is connected to?

Tags: ip, ssh

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to my Macbook Pro via ethernet, so I'm basically sharing my Macbook Pro's internet connection with my Raspberry Pi. I am connecting to my Raspberry Pi via SSH. The ethernet interface of my Macbook Pro has an IP address of `169.254.66.72`, and even if I use a static IP address for this interface, my Raspberry Pi always have an ip address of `192.168.2.5`. Why does my Raspberry Pi's IP address isn't `169.254.66.72`?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PI will not have the same IP address as your MacBook, that wouldn't work.

You don't have a diagram, so I have to assume the PI is connected to the MacBook via the ethernet, the MacBook is connecting to the LAN via Wi-Fi, and the MacBook is bridging the LAN.

The reason the MacBook has its address is that it doesn't have a DHCP server on the ethernet segment so it gets the IP address in the link-local address range (169.254.0.0/16).  The PI would then be getting its IP address from the DHCP server on the bridged LAN, the same place the MacBook gets its Wi-Fi IP address.